# Reading the sound level of a playing local audio file to generate a wu-meter in Android

Tags: android, audio

Is there any Android API that allows me to read the sound level of an audio file? Cause I need to write a visual effect which is generated by the audio level of a playing track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really an Android topic. I guess working with the Audio buffer will help you with that. Check out this link: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/197893

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html